# iptables trace behavior on mangle table

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to perform DNAT in my linux box and has the following table setup:

- Incoming packet's destination: 1.2.3.4
- Destination after DNAT: 5.6.7.8

```
$ iptables -t nat -L

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            1.2.3.4       to:5.6.7.8

...
```

Also there is a mangle table which I didn't put it on purpose but a default setup that I can't change for some reason:

```
$ iptables -L -n -t mangle
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
Some-PREROUTING  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain Some-from-host-endpoint (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain Some-PREROUTING (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0             mark match 0x10000/0x10000
Some-from-host-endpoint  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0             mark match 0x10000/0x10000
```

And when I check with tcpdump, I do see the destination packet 1.2.3.4 arrived to my interface. And I have my ip_forward setup to 1:

```
$ sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

And when I traced the packet by the following commands:

```
$ iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -d 1.2.3.4 -j TRACE
$ modprobe nf_log_ipv4
$ sysctl net.netfilter.nf_log.2=nf_log_ipv4
```

I do see the packets captured but the outcome confused me even further:

```
[17944.068093] TRACE: mangle:PREROUTING:policy:1 IN=eth0.123 OUT= MAC=12:34:56:78:ab:cd:ef:12:34:56:78:ab:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.123 DST=1.2.3.4 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=19764 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=3159 DPT=7878 SEQ=2715979345 ACK=0 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (309402198038ABEF398431232)
```

I am expecting that the destination address is changed to 5.6.7.8 and hitting the routing table entry for 5.6.7.8. But looks like it doesn't happen.

I have following questions:

1. Does it really match one entry (i.e., mangle:PREROUTING) or is it tracing upto one match?
2. If it is just hitting one matched entry, how come the matching ended up in mangle and not hitting the NAT table?
3. The trace says it matched "policy:1". Does it mean it matched the "Some-PREROUTING" target under PREROUTING? Or is it the first rule under "Some-PREROUTING" Chain?

Comment: Having DNAT in INPUT is a bug or a typo by OP. The man page tells "DNAT This  target is only valid in the nat table, in the PREROUTING and OUTPUT chains" . Please just provide this in the question: `iptables-save -c`. If it still shows DNAT in INPUT, please explain how to reproduce it (eg with my kernel and iptables I get this kernel message in `dmesg`: `x_tables: ip_tables: DNAT target: used from hooks INPUT, but only usable from PREROUTING/OUTPUT`)

Comment: Oops sorry that was my mistake while editing the question. It is indeed in PREROUTING. I'll update the question. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: While at it, please 1/ include the output of `iptables-save -c` instead . If you edit your output to avoid providing some parts, better change your test case so you don't have to edit anything. Edition = invisible cause of problems. 2/ please describe the commands you typed for your case to do the trace thus not requiring people to read the link on the trace method and be sure of what exactly was done or not done.

Comment: Good points AB. I updated (2) but I'm afraid can't do (1) as the system automatically rebuilds all those iptable rules so really can't operate with my own setup.